# Android SQLite query to prevent returning duplicate.

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I have a database as follows:

_ID  : SUBJECT : Topic :  LectureNumber

```
1 : WMCC   : RF       :     1
2 : WMCC   : Fading   :     2
3 : CCN    : IP       :     1
4 : CCN    : MAC      :     2
5 : WMCC   : Planning :     3
```

I have to place the queries in a List using SimpleCursorAdaptor such that

1)at first all subjects are placed in the List only once(No duplicates), i.e. the List displays only WMCC and CCN

2)when I click on a Subject Name, a new list is displayed containing all Lectures on that subject. e.g. If I click WMCC a new list is displayed containing all lectures on WMCC.

I am actually facing the problem in achieving the first task i.e PLACING SUBJECT NAMES IN A LIST USING SimpleCursorAdaptor only once.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in a "normalized" relational database, you would have a separate SUBJECTS table.  What you have shown above is not a "database" but a "*denormalized* table".

You could get the unique set of subjects from your denormalized table (let's call it LECTURES) so:

```
       select DISTINCT subject from LECTURES
```

The query to get the set of lectures for a given subject:

```
      select * from LECTURES where subject =  'the-subject-chosen-from-your-GUI-list'
```

Comment: Dear Tim,
I got you point. But i must have to include _ID as follows
    select DISTINCT _ID,subject from LECTURES
Because SimpleCursorAdapter needs _ID to work....However if i do so, the distinctness is removed because _ID is unique for every entry...and as a result i could not get what i want

Comment: The use of Group by solved the problem:

String sql="SELECT " +_ID+"," + SUBJECT + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " GROUP BY " +SUBJECT+";" ;

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,null);